# How to tag a word with different IOB tag in same corpus with Stanford NER?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am using below settings for Stanford NER

```
entitySubclassification sbieo
```

I have a corpus labeling (3 labels) like below.

```
1. operating expense
2. monthly expense bill
3. expense

operating   B-attribute
expense     E-attribute
monthly     B-attribute
expense     I-attribute
bill        E-attribute
expense     S-attribute
```

But on output for 'expense' keyword, I am getting I-attribute as best match. According to me, I should get S-attribute.

Please advice.